# Drawing polytope

Tags: graphics, computational-geometry, inequalities, polyhedra

Consider the $10 \times 3$ matrix ${\bf A}$ and the inequalities ${\bf A}{\bf x} \leq {\bf b}$:

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 1 & 1 \\ 
1 & 0 &1 \\ 
1 & 0 & 0\\ 
0 & 1 & 0\\ 
0 & 0 & -1 \\ 
0 &  0& 1\\ 
0 &  -1& 0\\ 
0 &  -1& 1\\ 
-1 &  0& 0\\ 
-1 &  0& 1
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
x_1\\ 
x_2\\ 
x_3
\end{bmatrix}
= 
\begin{bmatrix}
4\\
4\\
3\\ 
3\\ 
0\\
2\\
0\\
1\\
0\\
1 
\end{bmatrix}
$$

How can I show its shape from Mathematica?

[image]

Comment: Maybe ImplicitRegion?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
myA = {{0, 1, 1}, {1, 0, 1}, {1, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, -1}, 
      {0, 0, 1}, {0, -1, 0}, {0, -1, 1}, {-1, 0, 0}, {-1, 0, 1}};

b = {4, 4, 3, 3, 0, 2, 0, 1, 0, 1};

myregion = ImplicitRegion[
 And @@ Table[myA[[j]].{x, y, z} <= b[[j]], {j, Length[myA]}],
{x,y,z}]

RegionPlot3D[myregion, 
   PlotPoints -> 50, 
   Axes->True, 
   Mesh -> 5,
   MeshStyle -> Red,
   PlotStyle->Opacity[0.5]]
```

[image]